# SQL as does make a calculated field status

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Diagram Data Base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veXm5.png)

How can I make a calculated field that reads all Status_Jobs states and if all are in **"COMPLETE"**

Then Status_Project changes to **"COMPLETED"**

But if there are records with Status_Jobs in **"INCOMPLETE"**

Status_Project is **"INCOMPLETE"**

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Create a view instead!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @Status varchar(50)
if (Select count(*) from tablename where Status_Project ='Completed')=(Select count(*) from tablename)
set @Status='Completed'
ELSE
set @Status='InCompleted'

update tablename set Status=@Status
```